# How to get my program to output all values of the array Numbers to a file

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a lottery program within c++ and the issue i'm having is attempting to output all values of the Numbers array into a file, however when i run the code, the only thing that gets outputted is the first set of values i put in, however the program allows me to type in more than one set. (The program allows for up to 6 sets of data), however it only outputs one.
Here is all my code

LotteryData.cpp

```
LotteryData::LotteryData()
{
}

LotteryData::~LotteryData()
{
}

void LotteryData::PassInfo(int (&Numbers)[6][6], int &NumberofGames)
{
    ofstream Numfile;


    while(NumberofGames>0)
    {
        Numfile.open("Numbers.txt");
        for (int j=0; j<6; j++)
        {       
            Numfile << Numbers[NumberofGames][j];
        }
        NumberofGames = NumberofGames - 1;
        Numfile.close();
    }

}
```

Player.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class Player
{
private:

public:
Player();
~Player();
void Input(); 
int Numbers[6][6];
int NumberofGames;
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Lottery.h"
#include "Player.h"
#include "LotteryData.h"
using namespace std;

int main()  
{
Player player;
Lottery random;
LotteryData data;
player.Input();
random.setRandomNumber();
data.PassInfo(player.Numbers, player.NumberofGames);

}
```

Im not exactly sure where the problem is coming from but i think it may be from one of the pointers although not entirely sure.
Any help on this problem would be much appreciated.
Cheers

Edit: I've Changed the code within the PassInfo function within LotteryData.cpp file as @ali suggested
Edit2: I've cut down on the code as to where I think the problem occurs but as all of the code compiles, Visual Studio 2012 doesnt point to any actual errors in the program

Comment: Posting every single line of code you've written in your entire life as a programmer is a good start.  A better start might be writing a small program to just to the most minimal thing you're having a problem with.

Comment: I put all the code up to see if anybody noticed any errors within any of the other files that may solve the issue that im having with the program. no need to be sarcastic about it

Comment: You should invest in a debugger and actually use it.

Comment: i use visual studio 2012 but this doesnt help when it comes to issues such as this because visual studio doesnt see anything wrong

Comment: @user3097617 What nhgrif is trying to say is that it is generally considered good etiquette to narrow down code samples to the smallest possible part(s) which demonstrate the problem, cutting out all the irrelevant parts in the process. Nobody wants to have to decipher huge chunks of code. This is known as a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (click the link and read the guidance). Not only does this greatly assist the person trying to help you, but often you will actually solve the problem yourself in the process of coming up with the SSCCE.

Comment: @user3097617 Visual studio doesn't see anything wrong because you have a *logic* error i.e. the code compiles and runs, but doesn't behave as you want it to. That is one of the scenarios a debugger is good for - it steps you through the code line by line and lets you inspect variables as you go, so that you can see exactly at what point the code is misbehaving.

Answer (score 0):

In the `while` loop in the `PassInfo` function you are not changing the value of `NumberOfGames`. Therefore in the for loop you are using the same row of your `Numbers` array. You need another `for` loop to change the index for the first index of the `Numbers[][]` array.

Comment: Also note that using the do-while loops in your program the loops will execute once and then check the test condition for the while.